# Angular Highcharts - chart reference is gone after click

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

In the code you can see here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-example

when I go to export button -> select export pdf or png it works;
repeat this again -> it won't work since my chart object is empty!

How can I keep my reference on second click?

I tried keep it using jQuery, call initChart method before downloading and using pairwise operator in order to compare chart values.

None of this works.

All ode you can see in Stackblitz example

What should be result is that no matter how many time I export chart, chart reference stays there and chart is exported.

Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observable gets wrong chart object when you export chart. You need to check inner property `chart.options.chart.forExport` which is set to `true` when rendering chart for export.

```
private callback(chart: Highcharts.ChartObject) {
  if (chart.options.chart['forExport']) {
    return;
  }
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-example-ut62bf?file=src/app/shared/components/chart/chart.component.ts)**

Comment: Omg I lost so many hours yesterday and missed this point! Thanks a lot - it works like a charm!  And have a nice end of the weekend :)

Comment: @Yuniku_123 You're welcome! Please consired accepting the answer if it helped

Comment: I did, thanks once again! :)